# MariaDB running a LEFT JOIN query 100 times slower than Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, inner-join, mariadb

I am working on two terminals, in command lines only (no use of phpmyadmin here):

-MariaDB 10.1.9 (on a first computer working on Windows 10)

-Mysql 5.1.73 (on a second computer working on Windows 10)

I am runninng this specific command:

```
SELECT price, volume
    FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT fr.price,fr.volume,f.code_pays,fr.flux,fr.id_date, cf.code,fr.niv
      FROM fr_logical_data_2 fr
      INNER JOIN fr_pays f ON fr.id_code_pays = f.id
      INNER JOIN fr_nc8 n ON fr.id_code_nc8 = n.id
      INNER JOIN commodities_fr cf ON n.code_nc8 = cf.nc8
      WHERE cf.code = 'code_007' AND fr.flux= 1 AND f.code_pays = 'PT' AND fr.niv = 0
    ) AS Q
    ON Q.id_date = d.id
```

On Mysql,   it takes:         **0.1 sec**
On MariaDB, it takes: **4 min and 5 sec**

For the exact same result (49 rows) listed bellow
[result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLndP.png)

Note: The two computers usually have similar time of response

Note2: replacing the LEFT JOIN by an INNER JOIN gives the same time response between the two configuration (but the result is different of course). So i am thinking it could be the way MariaDB interpretes LEFT or RIGHT JOINs.

Does anyone have the same issue ?

Note3: I added the EXPLAIN SELECT... in pictures attached [EXPLAIN SELECT...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6NbK.png)

Comment: Are the tables indexed exactly the same in both maria and mysql ?

Comment: Yes the tables are indexed exactly the same

Comment: And type MyISAM is similar as well on both computers

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both.

Comment: How many rows (approx) in each table?

Comment: Hi Rick, I edited the post so that you can see the EXPLAIN SELECT result. You are on something... the answers to the EXPLAIN are different !
There is one "derived" table I have no clue about.

Comment: Number of rows per table:
Around 1000 for each table, except one (named 'fr' in the EXPLAIN) that has 1.8 M rows

Comment: just a question, why, against the current version of mariadb, are you using a very outdated version for mysql, 5.1.73, instead of 5.6.* or even 5.7.* ?

Comment: Simple: I re-installed recently one computer configuration, and wanted to try MariaDB instead of Mysql

Comment: Can you try with MariaDB once more after 

  SET SESSION optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';

then running EXPLAIN and the actual query in the same session?

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe wish your comment was an answer because it sure solved my problem. Switched from MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.3.9 and had a query jump to over 2 minutes from less than a second. Your suggestion for `optimizer_switch` took the query back down well below a second much to the delight of myself and my customer. Thank you!

Comment: I was actually trying to confirm whether you were running into an already reported bug. Unfortunately I didn't mention the bug number here, and now I'm not sure about which bug report it was anymore myself

Comment: @guillim this seems like an interesting problem to dive into, can you provide the scripts for the database generation and population for private testing?